# android Error:Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: android, xml

i was working on my program and electricity just switched off. so when i reopened my project its now giving me an error that says

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\Users\HP\AndroidStudioProjects\TheFarmer\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

when i try to navigate to the strings.xml folder in my windows exporer its giving me an error message that says

Cannot view XML input using style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later.

---

Invalid at the top level of the document. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/Users/HP/Desktop/Project/TheFarmer/app/src/...

please may someone help me out.

Comment: try rebuilding your project `Build -> Rebuild Project`

Comment: post your strings.xml.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open strings.xml in a regular text editor.  Whenever I get "Content is not allowed in prolog" it's usually because I have spaces or other characters before the "<?xml ..." first line.  Check that all your start tags have matching end tags.  You probably lost some data when the power went out, so you'll have to manually edit it back in.